# Split a column into two, using parenthesis as separator in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, gsub

I have a weird data format and I need to split a column to two.

```
col=c("142343-2344343(+)", "546354-4775458(-)", "374637463")
```

I want to split col to `col1` and `col2`, using the first parenthesis as separator.

I want something like this

```
     col1                 col2       
142343-2344343            +
546354-4775458            _
374637463                  NA
```

I d love your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `base R` with `read.csv`

```
read.csv(text = sub("(.*)([+-])$", "\\1,\\2", 
gsub("\\(|\\)", "", col)), header = FALSE, na.strings= "", 
col.names = c("col1", "col2"))
```

-output

```
             col1 col2
1 142343-2344343    +
2 546354-4775458    -
3      374637463 <NA>
```

---

With `tidyr`, an option is

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
tibble(col) %>% 
 separate_wider_regex(col, c(col1 = ".*", "\\(", var2 = "[^)]", 
    "\\)"), too_few = "align_start")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  col1           var2 
  <chr>          <chr>
1 142343-2344343 +    
2 546354-4775458 -    
3 374637463      <NA>
```

Comment: thats looks beatiful. I am such a newbie though. What if I want to use the separate function from tidyr. What would it be sep="", equal to?

Comment: @Corrector you can use the iupdate

Comment: wow! This is more than cool!

Answer (score 3):

Try `separate`:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(col) %>%
  separate(col,
          into = c("col1", "col2"),
          sep = "\\(|\\)")
            col1 col2
1 142343-2344343    +
2 546354-4775458    -
3      374637463 <NA>
```